# Why was Danzo after Shisui eyes?

Tags: naruto

This has been bugging me for a while. I'm very interested in Shisui's story of his life, but the real question is why was Donzo after his eye? Was it because of his sharingan? and "how is Donzo supposed to use this"?

Answer (score 1):

Shisui was one of the few members in the clan's history that was able to awaken the [Mangekyō Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan). It granted him access to a very powerful genjutsu, a unique technique noted to be of the highest caliber, Kotomatsukami. This technique allowed him to enter a person's mind and manipulate him or her by creating false experiences and illusions making it seem as though they were doing things of their own free will. The victim wouldn't be able to notice that they were being manipulated.

This Mangekyō Sharingan  are noted to be the *"heavenly eyes that see the truth of creation without obstruction"*. Hence Danzo was after Shisou's eyes.

[Source](http://naruto.wikia.com/g00/wiki/Shisui_Uchiha?i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvLmluLw%3D%3D&i10c.ua=1)

Comment: But how did he get the mangekyo sharingan what friend would he have killed ? or did he do it Sasukes way?

Comment: If you're asking as to how Shisui attained the Mangekyō Sharingan, Shisui has a darker side he was ashamed of. Out of envy to a friend who he had believed had surpassed him in ability, Shishui withheld his aid at a very critical moment resulting in the other shinobi's death. The guilt caused by the same led Shisui to consider himself to be a murderer causing him to awaken the Mangekyō Sharingan.

Comment: So mainly that would be how Sasuke would accomplish it from his envy to Naruto? He was jealous of Naruto and he had seemed dark on revenge as he went on Orochimarus side?!